# Storing Data in Cassandra and Visualizing it in ThingsBoard Dashboard

Tags: thingsboard, telemetry

I'm working on a project where I need to store data in Cassandra and visualize it in a dashboard using ThingsBoard. I have already set up a Cassandra cluster and designed the data schema. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to connect ThingsBoard to the Cassandra cluster and display the data in the dashboard.

Could you please advise if there is a more efficient way to store data and visualize it later in thingsboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThingsBoard already has it's own Cassandra schema, therefore it would be more efficient to use it for visualizing the data in dashboards.

You can use several APIs for sending the data to ThingsBoard e.g. via MQTT or HTTP:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/api/

If you have the Professional Edition of ThingsBoard, you could also use Integrations & Data Converter:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/

Comment: Thank you  for providing your answer! Currently, I'm utilizing Thingsboard community edition for my project. My goal is to store telemetry data whenever needed, so I can visualize it later. However, I'm unsure about how to configure Cassandra properly to store this data. My question is whether Thingsboard can preview the stored data in the database once it's configured correctly. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me with this inquiry. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Setup thingsboard with hybrid database (Postgres+Cassandra): https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/pe/ubuntu/?ubuntuThingsboardDatabase=hybrid#step-4-configure-thingsboard-database (Then all incoming telemtries will be stored in Cassandra DB and are available for visualization in Dashboards)

Comment: then use the API's to send data to thingsboard: https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/api/ (I would recommend MQTT for this)

Comment: Thank you much, I really appropriate your help.